# How to permanently change the appearance of a button onclick in a flask webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, cs50

Excuse my ignorance but I am completing Harvard's CS50 at the minute and pursuing the web track, working on my final project.

I am creating a website, one of the functions of which is to track applications using buttons within a table. On click the buttons change appearance to suit the given application status, as shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfgbN.png

However, currently the webpage does not save data for individual users so the buttons revert to their original form (Not started). How do I go about implementing this (I spent many hours trying to save the status of each button into SQL but cant work it out).

Heres the code i have at the moment:

**Python/flask**

```
@app.route("/summertable")
@login_required
def summertable():
    firms = db.execute("SELECT firm_name FROM firm_names")
    return render_template("table.html", firms=firms)
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quote
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <table class="table-striped tracker" style="table-align" id="tracker">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left">Firms</th>
            <th>Spring weeks</th>
            <th>Asset management</th>
            <th>Investment banking</th>
            <th>Risk</th>
            <th>Global Markets</th>
        </tr>
        {% for firm in firms %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ firm.firm_name }}</td>
                <td><button onclick="submitButtonStyle(this)" type="submit" class="btn button" name="spring">Not started</button></td>
                <td><button onclick="submitButtonStyle(this)" type="submit" class="btn button" name="asset">Not started</button></td>
                <td><button onclick="submitButtonStyle(this)" type="submit" class="btn button" name="ib">Not started</button></td>
                <td><button onclick="submitButtonStyle(this)" type="submit" class="btn button" name="risk">Not started</button></td>
                <td><button onclick="submitButtonStyle(this)" type="submit" class="btn button" name="markets">Not started</button></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <script>
    function submitButtonStyle(_this) {
            if (_this.innerHTML === "Not started") {
                _this.style.backgroundColor = "LightSalmon";
                _this.innerHTML = "In progress...";
                i ++;
            }
            else if (_this.innerHTML === "In progress...") {
                _this.style.backgroundColor = "PaleGreen";
                _this.innerHTML = "Applied";
            }
            else {
                _this.style.backgroundColor = "LightCoral";
                _this.innerHTML = "Not started";
            }
    }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The answer is you need a model for each element that has all properties set on change.  Each model then is a part of an array. Each time a model changes the array is persisted.  To restore state use the array to set values.  This concept is named binding.

Comment: How do I go about implementing this? In javascript?

Comment: for firm in firms, is submitted but the response is not returning the changes.  Rember that there is no state stored between requests. The response must provide new state.